# How to find a name=id pair in an sql string and replace it with another value and update it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a lot of records in a table `News`.

Each record has `NewsRoleId`, `NewsTitle` and a `URL`.

The `URL` is like

```
http://ournews.com/View-News;NewsId=56122;OrderId=1;pt=5
```

Each `NewsTitle` would return you exactly 2 records; not more not less but different `NewsRoleID`; for example:

```
    ID         NewsTitle       NewsRoleId       URL
    1             Test            124           http://ournews.com/View;newsId=44;OrderId=1;pt=5
   `2             Test            138`          http://ournews.com/View;newsId=32;OrderId=1;pt=5
```

Now, the goal is to `UPDATE` the `newsId` in `URL` by `ID` of one record with another i.e. `Id` of the record with `NewsRoleID= 124` should be updated in the `newsId` of `URL` of record with `NewsRoleId= 138` and vice versa.

**Desired Output:**

```
D         NewsTitle       NewsRoleId       URL
1           Test              124          http://ournews.com/View;newsId=2;OrderId=1;pt=5

2           Test              138          http://ournews.com/View;newsId=1;OrderId=1;pt=5
```

I have written an update query.

```
Update News
SET URL= REPLACE(Url, 'newsID=123433', 'newsId='+CAST(Select Id from News where NewsTitle= 'test' and NewsRoleID= 124) as varchar)
where NewsRoleID = 138 and NewsTitle = 'test'
```

But Problem with this is that I cannot exactly find the pair `‘NewsId=the Id which is random’`

Comment: Given the option, I wouldn't do the URL parsing and manipulation in TSQL. If I had to run this server-side I'd consider some SQL CLR to help or, I'd write a client application in a language with good support for URL manipulation.

Comment: @Jodrell its a one time query;

Comment: its one time until you discover that your TSQL string manipulation altered a URL in a way that you didn't anticipate because it turns out your sample of test data omitted an edge case. If you use some hardened code that handles edge cases around URLs you might avoid some pain. If the number of rows is trivial, you could just adjust it, one time, by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
declare @news table 
    (
        ID int,
        NewsTitle nvarchar(100),
        NewsRoleId int,
        [URL] nvarchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO @news VALUES
(1, 'Test', 124, 'http://ournews.com/View;newsId=44;OrderId=1;pt=5'),
(2, 'Test', 138, 'http://ournews.com/View;newsId=32;OrderId=1;pt=5');

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ID, CHARINDEX('newsId=', [URL], 1) AS nPos FROM @news),
CTE2 AS
(SELECT n.ID, CHARINDEX(';', [URL], c.nPos) AS scPos FROM @news 
n INNER JOIN CTE c ON n.ID = c.ID )
UPDATE n
SET URL = SUBSTRING(n.[URL], 1, c1.NPos -1) 
+ 'newsId=' + cast(nOther.Id as nvarchar)
+ SUBSTRING(n.[URL], c2.scPos, 300)
FROM CTE c1 
INNER JOIN CTE2 c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID
INNER JOIN @news n ON c1.ID = n.ID
INNER JOIN @news nOther ON n.NewsTitle = nOther.NewsTitle 
    AND n.NewsRoleId <> nOther.NewsRoleId;
    
SELECT * FROM @news;
```

Output:

| ID | NewsTitle | NewsRoleId | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 124 | http://ournews.com/View;newsId=2;OrderId=1;pt=5 |
| 2 | Test | 138 | http://ournews.com/View;newsId=1;OrderId=1;pt=5 |

By way of explanation, I use two CTEs to identify the position where "newsid=" occurs and the first semi-colon following this.  The trick is then to build the new string using a self-join on the news table, with the same NewsTitle but differing NewsRoleIDs.  This allows us to put the "Other" ID into the new URL.

Comment: let me try this. thanks a lot

Comment: all heroes don't wear caps. You sir, a legend. Thanks a lot. I wish my mind could work like you.

Comment: @testy, just checking, all the newsId query string parameters are integers. There are none that use URI escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
With CTE AS
(
  Select ID, NewsTitle, NewsRoleId, URL,
       REPLACE(URL, 
               SUBSTRING(URL, 
                         CHARINDEX(';', URL)+1,  
                         CHARINDEX(';', URL, CHARINDEX(';', URL)+1) -(CHARINDEX(';',URL))
                        ),
               CONCAT('newsId=',Case When ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By NewsTitle Order By ID) = 1
                    Then LEAD(ID) Over (Partition By NewsTitle Order By ID)
                    ELSE LAG(ID) Over (Partition By NewsTitle Order By ID)
               End,';')
              ) NEW_URL
From News
)

Update CTE Set URL = NEW_URL;

Select * From News;
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0xyEfKx7).